# How to convert this script into a custom mercurial command?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, version-control, mercurial

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
        echo -n "$0 - a utility for applying uncommitted changes to a "
        echo "remote hg repository locally also"
        echo "Usage: $0 user@hostname path/to/repository"
        exit -1
fi
user_at_hostname="$1"
remote_path="$2"

ssh "$user_at_hostname" hg -R "$remote_path" diff | hg import --no-commit -
```

It's not the most glorious piece of code, and I would rather do something more "mercurial" than that, so to speak. Specifically, I was wondering whether I could achieve the same using a mercurial alias / custom command. Can I?

PS - I had also thought about maybe issuing some sort of shelve command on the remote repository instead of just getting a diff, but I don't want to make thing too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to convert this script into an `hg foo` command without changing it, use a shell [alias](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#alias).  Just copy the last line and replace the custom variables with `$1` and `$2`.

If you want to make this look more like a "normal" Mercurial workflow, you could start by committing the changes and then pulling them.  I imagine that you are avoiding this workflow so that you can change your mind about these modifications without polluting your repository's history with "oops" commits.  If that is the case, then you will likely be interested in the [Evolve extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/EvolveExtension).  The Evolve extension is intended to provide a safe and reasonably well-behaved system for sharing mutable history.  In this way, you can commit a change; share it with another repository; amend, rebase, squash, or otherwise modify the change; and then share the modified changeset with the same repository or a different one.  You can also prune changesets from history and share the fact that you pruned them.  If this sharing causes problems, such as amending a commit which has descendants, Mercurial will detect those problems and offer a fix (e.g. rebase the descendants onto the new version of the commit) which you can execute automatically with `hg evolve`.  While the extension is still experimental, it does basically work for most simple use cases.

If experimental software isn't of interest to you, you can still flag the repository as [non-publishing](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Phases#Publishing_Repository).  This will allow you to use more traditional history-editing machinery such as `hg rebase`, `hg histedit`, and [`hg strip`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/StripExtension) even after you have pushed to the repository.  However, revisions which are destroyed in one repository will not automatically vanish from other repositories without the evolve extension.  You will have to strip them by hand.

Finally, note that `hg push --force` *does not* destroy revisions.  It creates new anonymous branches, typically resulting in a messy history, but without actually losing any data.  It is different from `git` in this fashion.

Comment: I didn't quite follow your first paragraph. Do you mean I should use a shell alias for the last line and not use `.hgrc` aliasing at all?

Comment: You should use an `.hgrc` alias, specifically the kind that can run arbitrary shell commands.  These are called "shell aliases."